# Set min value for bar chart in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to make a nice bar chart which shows overtime hours, and ideally it would have a max of 100 hours (100 hours overtime), and minimum of -100 hours (100 hours undertime).

I have been trying to get chart.js to work, but I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  I have the chart showing a bar from -10 to 50, but it isn't honouring the max/min values I have set as per the docs.  Do these settings work with horizontal bar charts?

My jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/retrodans/8dp0k29r/31/

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

const data = {
  datasets: [{
    label: 'hrs',
    data: [
      [-10, 50]
    ],
  }],
  labels: ["Overtime"]
};

const options = {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        min: -100,
        max: 100,
        suggestedMin: -200,
        suggestedMax: 200,
        beginAtZero: false
      }]
    }
};

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options,
  });
```

Any help and tips would be most appreciated,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in your JSFiddle, you're using the latest version of Chart.js (currently v4.3.0) but your `options` are still of format v2.n.

Define `options` as follows and it will work.

```
const options = {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        display: true,
        min: -100,
        max: 100,
        beginAtZero: false,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false
        }
      }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `x` key in the `scales` with just an object with `min` and `max`:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

const data = {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'hrs',
        data: [
            [-10, 50]
        ],
    }],
    labels: ["Overtime"]
};

const options = {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        x: {
            display: true,
            min: -100,
            max: 100,
            beginAtZero: false,

        }
    }
};

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div>
    <canvas id="myChart" height="120"></canvas>
</div>
```